# What to do when you're AFK and then come back and then there is writen: move to pick up where you left of and it doesnt work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was recently AFK in-game, and later when I wanted to play Minecraft, on screen was the text: YOU ARE AFK, move to pick up where you left off. I did that and I still have same text on screen, I can move and break blocks, but I hardly can see anything.  What can I do to remove this text?

Comment: please provide more information on your game envrioment. (Version, Server, and any/all mods)

Answer (score 1):

Try re-starting your game, or if you were on a server, logging off then back on. This should fix your issue. If you were using a single player map and restarting your game doesn't work then you'll either have to find the command block causing this (and breaking it), or just re-download the world to start again.